# Regex: ccTLD wildcard detection/removal in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have an url like this one:

> http://xenodesystems.blogspot**.com**/2013/07/actualizarmigrar-ruby-20-y-rails-4-sin.html

But the **".com"** over there can change depending on the country, so that url also works with:

> http://xenodesystems.blogspot**.mx**/2013/07/actualizarmigrar-ruby-20-y-rails-4-sin.html
>   http://xenodesystems.blogspot**.it**/2013/07/actualizarmigrar-ruby-20-y-rails-4-sin.html
>   http://xenodesystems.blogspot**.fr**/2013/07/actualizarmigrar-ruby-20-y-rails-4-sin.html

etc.

What I need to do is replacing **"xenodesystems.blogspot.*"** with **"blog.xenodesystems.com"** and leave the rest of the URL intact, like this:

> http://blog.xenodesystems.com/2013/07/actualizarmigrar-ruby-20-y-rails-4-sin.html

Is this possible to do with javascript? I know blogger can redirect a domain, but I need to do it in pure Javascript explicitly. I know it's possible, it's just matter of finding the right regex, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ([JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tZSEX/)). No regular expressions so it's much more efficient:

```
var str="http://xenodesystems.blogspot.mx/2013/07/actualizarmigrar-ruby-20-y-rails-4-sin.html";
 function xIndexOf(Val, Str, x)  
 {  
   if (x <= (Str.split(Val).length - 1)) {  
     Ot = Str.indexOf(Val);  
     if (x > 1) { for (var i = 1; i < x; i++) { var Ot = Str.indexOf(Val, Ot + 1) } }  
     return Ot;
   }
 }
var slash = (xIndexOf('/',str,3));
var dot = (xIndexOf('.',str,2));
str = str.substring(0,dot)+".com"+str.substring(slash)
alert(str)
```

xIndexOf function taken from [here](http://webmisterradixlecti.blogspot.com/2012/10/javascript-secondindexof-or-xindexof.html).

Comment: This alerts the whole string without changes O.o what is it supposed to do?

Comment: No the `str` variable has the .mx TLD but for me at least it alerts with .com

Comment: it works flawlessly :D Thank you (And thanks for the link about xIndexOf)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean:

```
var urls = [
  'http://xenodesystems.blogspot.mx/2013/07/actualizarmigrar-ruby-20-y-rails-4-sin.html',
  'http://xenodesystems.blogspot.it/2013/07/actualizarmigrar-ruby-20-y-rails-4-sin.html',
  'http://xenodesystems.blogspot.fr/2013/07/actualizarmigrar-ruby-20-y-rails-4-sin.html',
  'http://xenodesystems.blogspot.com.au/2013/07/actualizarmigrar-ruby-20-y-rails-4-sin.html',
];

var ret = new Array;
var len = urls.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
  ret.push(urls[i].replace(/xenodesystems.blogspot(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+)+/,'xenodesystems.blogspot.com'));
}
console.log(ret);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
["http://xenodesystems.blogspot.com/2013/07/actualizarmigrar-ruby-20-y-rails-4-sin.html",
"http://xenodesystems.blogspot.com/2013/07/actualizarmigrar-ruby-20-y-rails-4-sin.html",
"http://xenodesystems.blogspot.com/2013/07/actualizarmigrar-ruby-20-y-rails-4-sin.html",
"http://xenodesystems.blogspot.com/2013/07/actualizarmigrar-ruby-20-y-rails-4-sin.html"]
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7T3xP/)